# Test file upload in Flask

Tags: testing, flask, upload

I have a flask's controller (POST) to upload a file:

```
f = request.files['external_data']
filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
f.save(filename)
```

I have tried to test it:

```
handle = open(filepath, 'rb')
fs = FileStorage(stream=handle, filename=filename, name='external_data')
payload['files'] = fs
url = '/my/upload/url'
test_client.post(url, data=payload)
```

But in the controller `request.files` contains:

```
ImmutableMultiDict: ImmutableMultiDict([('files', <FileStorage: u'myfile.png' ('image/png')>)])
```

My tests pass in case I replace `'external_data'` with `'files'`

How is it possible to create [flask test](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/) request that contains `request.files('external_data')`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the origin from `payload`, which is the issue.

payload should probably be a `.copy()` of a `dict()` version of your original object.